# Roll up multiple rows into one postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a role table

```
id |created_at             |updated_at             |role           |source |username
7  |2019-12-01 01:38:31.965|2019-12-01 01:38:31.965|ROLE_ADMIN     |ACCESS |mammar
8  |2019-12-01 01:38:33.061|2019-12-01 01:38:33.061|ROLE_SUPERADMIN|ACCESS |mammar
```

How do I get the output as using SQL query :

```
username;role 
mammar , ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERADMIN
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek, please check the solution what I have given below and let me know if still any issue.

Comment: please try again ,I have done some changes in my query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below query for your problem and let me know if still you are facing any issue.

```
    SELECT username
    ,STRING_AGG(ROLE, ',' ORDER BY ROLE) roles
FROM [Your_schema].ROLE
 GROUP BY username;
```

Comment: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. I am on Postgres v9.6

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```sql
SELECT username, STRING_AGG(role) AS role
FROM my_table
GROUP BY username
;
```

This will group the `role` entries within each `username` into a single field.